# XCTest/XCTest.h not found error in XCODE 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

I updates my xcode to 6.1.1. Now facing this error.

[image]

How to add XCTest.framwork. I tried adding using normal procedure of adding framework but not getting option of XCTest.framework

Comment: Could you share your project via github or any if possible that way it would be easier to dig it out Or simply clean your project remove the XCTest and add it again.

Comment: @walle84. Thanks for you advice. Bymistakenly have added the {projectname}Tests.m file to the compile sources. I removed it . Now working fine. Do you have any idea why not to add test files to compile sources. Thank you

Comment: You need to add test file to compile source, e.g. NetworkTest.m and also all other files having dependency to run the test methods.